# How do I get to the implementation code of Delegate's virtual method like invoke?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, clr

I know when I define a delegate type, the compiler automatically generates the delegate type and adds several virtual methods such as 'invoke'。

But it's a virtual method, and the implementation code is implemented in 'CLR' by the c++ .So,how do I find this implementation code?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that is not open source.  Microsoft does have some licensed or proprietary code within the runtime.  You could, of course, attempt disassembly but YMMV.

Comment: Thank you, but that is to say, this will be my eternal problem.